# Building a party app with Google Maps Android API?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, heatmap

I am trying to make an Android app that show's where users are on a Google Maps Heatmap in the app, so that users can see what parts of their college campus are popular - for example, so users can find college parties.  I implemented the app a year ago, but found that the map showed individual users as green dots on the map, violating users privacy. I want to remake the app without this problem.  Is there a way I can configure the Google map Heatmap to not show individual users as dots and instead show just a broad swath of green where users are? I want to be able to show users where there is a high concentration of other users (e.g. a popular party) without giving away users' locations.

Answer (score 0):

I once implemented **Google Heatmap utility** , and i never got that problem with green point to show a user exact location , maybe you did wrong with the heat opacity and radius , i remember my heat opacity was set at `0.3` and my radius at `50`.

And also make sure you are not using  weighted latitude/longitude points , as mentioned from the doc

> When creating a `HeatmapTileProvider`, you can pass it a collection of
>   weighted latitude/longitude coordinates. This is useful if you want to
>   illustrate the importance of a particular set of locations.
>
> - Create a new `WeightedLatLng` for each location that requires weighting. Pass in the `LatLng` and a double representing the intensity
>     required. The intensity indicates the relative importance, or value,
>     of this location

If you can provide more information about your implementation ( code ) it would be great !